# Jquery one event handler for multiple elements and events

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to figure out how I can make this code in only one eventhandler... 
So it knows what element has been clicked and from there executes the right .text action on the correct element. Any ideas? :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#knapp1").on("click", function(){
        $("#hund").text("Voff!");
    });

        $("#knapp2").on("click", function(){
        $("#katt").text("Miau!");
    });

        $("#knapp3").on("click", function(){
        $("#gris").text("Nöff!");
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Perhaps there is some sort of pattern.. are the elements descendants?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: @JoshCrozier we don't actually need to see his html to help with this

Comment: @yuvi Of course you don't need to, but it would help us provide a better, more intuitive solution.

Comment: @JoshCrozier nah, I think it just clutters his very concise and clear question. let him figure out how to implement the answer on his own

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use a class, and add some inner logic. For example - using `data-*` attrs would be the cleanest:

```
<button class="knapp" data-target="targetid" data-text="new text">click me!</button>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".knapp").on('click', function() {
          var $this  = $(this),              // so I only call $(this) once
              target = $this.data('target'), // grab target
              text   = $this.data('text');   // grab text
        
        $(target).text(text); // finally, execute
    });
});
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
button { background: white; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px; padding: 5px; }
div { margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="knapp" data-target="#hund" data-text="Voff!">Dog goes</button>
<button class="knapp" data-target="#katt" data-text="Miau!">Cat goes</button>
<button class="knapp" data-target="#gris" data-text="Nöff!">Gris(?) goes</button>

<div>
    <span id="hund">hund</span>
    <br />
    <span id="katt">katt</span>
    <br />
    <span id="gris">gris</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have catched the idea, do you mean something like this:

####HTML

```
<div id="group1">
    <span id="knapp1" data-content="Voff!">hund</span>
    <br />
    <span id="knapp2" data-content="Miau!">katt</span>
    <br />
    <span id="knapp3" data-content="Nöff!">gris</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="hund"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="katt"></span>
    <br />
    <span id="gris"></span>
</div>
```

#####JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#group1 span").on('click', function() {
        selectorid=$(this).text();
        texttoput=$(this).attr("data-content");
        $("#"+selectorid).text(texttoput);
    });
});
```

See JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skfd8b84/

Answer (score -3):

With jQuery, you can combine selectors using commas. It could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#knapp1, #knapp2, #knapp3").on("click", function(){
      //`this` now refers to the element that was clicked.
  });
});
```

Depending on your situation, this is probably better suited for a class to be on those elements instead.

You could then use data attributes in HTML to handle the correct actions:

```
<div id="knapp1" data-animal="hund" data-animal-sound="Voff"></div>
```

So that you can then set the correct values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#knapp1, #knapp2, #knapp3").on("click", function(){
      var animal = $(this).data('animal');
      var sound = $(this).data('animal-sound');
      $("#"+animal).text(sound+"!");
  });
});
```